# Работа со шрифтом в css

Tags: css3, photoshop, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте,

Пробую сверстать макет PSD и получилась загвордка.
В макете есть текст, шрифт которого в Photoshop отображается так:

[image]

Сам шрифт MyriadPro-Semibold.otf установлен в Windows.

Как мне с ним работать через css (проблема в работе с типом Semibold)? Не прибегая к font-face.
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: А как насчет google fonts API?

Comment: Не хочеться подключать ничего лишнего ( по этому и отказались от font-face )

Comment: Semibold это полужирный?
Если у вас такой шрифт есть на компьютере, то в css работайте с ним через свойства текста. font-family: 'MyriadPro'; font-weight: bold и т.д.
Или я не до конца понял Ваш вопрос?

Comment: переводится как полужирный, а "font-weight: bold" это жирный. Нужен полужирный.

Comment: В css нет значения для полужирного. Используйте уже готовый шрифт ( который будет полужирным).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rtfm [CSS font-weight Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)

normal, bold, bolder, lighter, 100..900, inherit

Answer (score 0):

я решил эту задачу при помощи следующих стилей:

```
font-weight:normal;
text-shadow:1px 0 0 #(такой же цвет как текст)
```

выглядит так же как и `semibold`